# Private key on Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key-export

I can't create the private key of a legacy address on bitcoin core. When I do the command it writes me that it can only be done to legacy addresses. And my address is legacy. What should I do. Thank you

Comment: Hello Carmen, what are you trying to do that you need to export a private key for? Perhaps if you ask about your original problem instead of your solution attempt for that problem, we could help you better.

Comment: why is the private key, which allows you to have full control over moving your wallet/addresses between bitcoin clients so elusive to obtain? @Murch

Comment: Because Bitcoin Core moved to a more comprehensive export format, _ouput script descriptors_ a few years ago.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're confusing legacy *addresses* with legacy *wallets*. They're distinct and unrelated things.

- Legacy *addresses* are pre-segwit addresses (P2PKH most commonly), and are contrasted with segwit and taproot addresses.
- Legacy wallets are wallet files in the BDB file format, created by old versions of Bitcoin Core (and can still be opened by new versions, for now). They're contrasted with descriptor wallets, which use the SQLite file format, which are created by newer versions of Bitcoin Core.

You can create legacy addresses using descriptor wallets, and you can create segwit (but not taproot) addresses using legacy wallets.

What I suspect is going on here is that you're trying to perform the `dumpprivkey` on a legacy address in a descriptor wallet. And that doesn't work, because `dumpprivkey` only works on legacy wallets (regardless of address type). Exporting private key is dangerous, and especially so for descriptor wallets (where an attacker can typically compute *all* your private keys from just one). If you must, you can export the private master key using `listdescriptors`, though I suspect this will not be what you want.

To help you find an alternative, I encourage you to amend your answer to explain exactly what you're trying to achieve (or point out if my interpretation of events is incorrect). Perhaps a solution exists that doesn't involve exporting private keys, as that is generally a bad idea unless you really know what you are doing.