# cannot export my private key from bitcoin core wallet

Tags: wallet, private-key-export

attempting to export private key from bitcoin core wallet with no pass phrase, when i enter the command "dumpprivkey" with my bitcoin address, it says, Only legacy wallets are supported by this command (code -4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Private key on Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/120439/private-key-on-bitcoin-core) or [Why can I not dump private keys from a descriptor wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/113834/13866)